# How to convert 0²0 36 0 ² 6 4 to 020360264 in python?

Tags: python

Assumed I have **string** : 0²0 36 0 ² 6 4

How can I convert it into **string** : 020360264

Answer (score 1):

```py
s = "0²0 36 0 ² 6 4"
s = s.replace("²", "2")  # replace the funky 2
s = "".join(c for c in s if c.isdigit())  # keep digits only
print(s)
```

Outputs, as expected, `020360264`

Answer (score 0):

this is a variant:

```
strg = "0²0 36 0 ² 6 4"
strg = strg.translate(str.maketrans({"²": "2", " ": None}))
# 020360264
```

using [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to remove all the spaces and convert `'²'` to `'2'`.